# Hide and show column field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide table column with `id='ch-forms-grid_c4'` when body `class="skin-blue sidebar-mini"`. And I need to show this column when body `class="skin-blue sidebar-mini sidebar-collapse"`. How can I do it?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I do not not javascript and I have no any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Black magic with good old css:

```
body.sidebar-mini #ch-forms-grid_c4 {
    display: none;
}

body.sidebar-collapse #ch-forms-grid_c4 {
    display: block;
}
```

This hides your element if the body does have the class "sidebar-mini". If the body does have the class "sidebar-collapse", it'll be shown.
This matches exactly your specifications.